# Grunt, Less, and File Watching

Tags: less, gruntjs

I'm trying to get grunt working to do something. My project looks like this:

```
/app
    /assets
        /components
        /stylesheets
            /less
                /file1.less
                /file2.less
                /file3.less
                /importAll.less
            /css
```

I want it so that when `file1`, `file2`, or `file3` are saved the `importAll.less` file is compiled into css and put into `/css/style.css`. This is as far as I got.

```
less: {
    development: {
        options: {
            paths: ["./assets/stylesheets/less"],
            yuicompress: true
        },
        files: {
            "./assets/stylesheets/css/style.css": "./assets/stylesheets/less/importAll.less"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the file watcher working.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I got it working with the following!

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["./assets/stylesheets/less"],
                    yuicompress: true
                },
                files: {
                    "./assets/stylesheets/css/style.css": "./assets/stylesheets/less/style.less"
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: "./assets/stylesheets/less/*",
            tasks: ["less"]
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

Comment: For a newbie like me, it will probably help mentioning that to run only `grunt` you need to define the default task like `grunt.registerTask('default','watch');` For reference [docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask)

Comment: how does it know to run `less:development`, when you can have multiple tasks within the `less {}` block?

Comment: @WillshawMedia to run only the "development" part, use `grunt less:development`. `grunt less` will run all under `less`

Comment: Another heads-up for newbies (like me)  - you need to stop your current watch task and restart it in order for changes to the task to take effect (CTRL + C to stop).