# Compile Less on the server?

Tags: css, wordpress, gruntjs

A friend and I work on WordPress projects together. I work locally and preprocess my css with LESS. He doesn't. He wants to start using LESS, but doesn't work locally (and can't for a few reasons).  At the moment, my choice is to write all the LESS, or to give up using LESS on these projects and write vanilla css — both options are less than ideal.

Is there a way for both of us to use LESS if he doesn't work locally?  Is there was a way to detect a change in the `.less` file on the server and recompile?  Can Grunt help with this?

Thanks!

Terry

ps:  I use git and stuff too, and of course we don't work on live production sites. This is just for early collaboration and prototyping.

Comment: I'm curious as to why your friend CAN'T work locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. There are some great grunt plugins for this.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch
and
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less

also this post details a sample configuration you might find interesting.

[Grunt, Less, and File Watching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664628/grunt-less-and-file-watching)