# How can I customise Bootstrap without losing the changes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, bower

I'm using Bower to manage Bootstrap and would like to make some changes (colours, font size etc) to the default Bootstrap look and feel. Here's my workflow:

1. Edit `bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less`
2. Recompile bootstrap using `grunt build`

The problem is that I want to be able to upgrade bootstrap when a new version comes out and presumably I'll lose my changes to `variables.less`.

Is there a way I can keep my changes outside of `bower_components` and also avoid having `bower_components` in source control since it's 122MB?

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes, with yours and various other answers I've figured it out. Answer posted below. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a `variables-custom.less` and import it into `theme.less` like this:

```
//
// Load core variables and mixins
// --------------------------------------------------

@import "variables.less";
//import custom-variables after variables so the values will override.
@import "custom-variables.less"; //only has variables that have changed.
@import "mixins.less";
```

IMO this is a little bit better than the first solution because you wont have to load two (almost) identical CSS files on the client.

I'm sorry I cant help you with what to to about Bower and your source control as I do not use Bower

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution which worked for me:

- Use `bower` to install all UI packages e.g. `bower install bootstrap chosen`
- Create a separate folder `less` which contains all the LESS modifications. [This article was very helpful here](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial).

Here's my `less/styles.less` file:

```
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-chosen/bootstrap-chosen.less";

//My custom variables - overrides the bootstrap variables file
@import "variables-custom.less";
```

- Use `grunt` to monitor changes within the `less` folder and compile them into .css

Here's my `Gruntfile.js` ([thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664628/grunt-less-and-file-watching/15664986#15664986)):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    paths: ["./less"],
                    yuicompress: true
                },
                files: {
                    "./static/css/styles.css": "./less/styles.less"
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: "./less/*",
            tasks: ["less"]
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

Comment: the problem with doing it this way is: what if the variable file changes? you will have to mirror the changes into your customized variable file. but if you simply override the necessary variables in your custom-variables, you would have fewer changes to make. it is more DRY to override rather than recreate

Comment: That's what my `variables.less` file does, it just overrides some of the bootstrap variables. Perhaps I should rename it to `variables-custom.less`

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24770216/1162235) is indeed the best customization method. You create a theme.less and pull in original Bootstrap files (which can get upgraded in the future) and in the same file you call your own custom overrides. Either you @import them from a custom file which is not in the Bower directory or you just write your custom rules in your theme.less itself. You'll find this technique explained in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594098/How-to-customize-Twitter-Bootstrap-to-fit-your-web) tutorial as well.

With Grunt, custom setups can get tricky. But with [Brunch](http://brunch.io) it's a piece of cake (yes!) and all pretty much goes automatically. Your grandma could do it.

As for avoiding the inclusion of `bower_components` in source control: with Git it's easy. You just check-in your bower.json but make sure to add `/bower_components` to your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should just create your own style sheet, use both with your custom one listed secondly. That way you can make changes but not change bootstrap at all.

Also, when you update, you keep your style sheet the same.

This allows you to change bits and pieces of Bootstrap but not actually changing the file, you're overriding it.

To be clear, your second CSS file would be SIGNIFICANTLY smaller... Only putting things your needed to change in it.