# linux less compiler watch for @import updates

Tags: css, less

I'm looking for a LESS compiler for Ubuntu, which supports auto-compile on saves, and checks not only for main file, but also its `@import`ed files within it.

When I was on Windows, [WinLESS](http://winless.org/) does the work perfectly.

Command-line or GUI not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and especially [grunt-contib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch), see [Grunt, Less, and File Watching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664628/grunt-less-and-file-watching) for an example.

Notice that also the client side less.js compiler has got a watch function, see http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-watch-mode.